# How to draw a non-standard graph?

Tags: graphs

I want to draw the following graph:
[image]

I scanned the whole [documentation of tkz-berge](http://ctan.altspu.ru/obsolete/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-berge/doc/tkz-berge-screen.pdf), but didn't find how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be drawn with usual TikZ code via `node`s. A minimal working example MWE is expected in next questions if any.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\a{1}
\path[nodes={circle,draw,minimum size=5mm}]
(0,0) node (C) {}
(\a,\a) node (R1) {}
(2*\a,0) node (R2) {}
(\a,-\a) node (R3) {}
(-\a,\a) node (L1) {}
(-2*\a,0) node (L2) {}
(-\a,-\a) node (L3) {};
\path 
(R2)+(0:.5) node{$t$}
(L2)+(180:.5) node{$s$};
\foreach \p/\q in {C/R1,C/R2,R1/R2,R3/R2,L2/L1,L2/L3,L3/C,L1/C,L1/R1,L3/R3}
\draw[->] (\p)--(\q);
    
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just my comment is an observation: but the arrow below is it with the same tick or is the quality of the image? For me it is approved 

Comment: @Sebastiano I use PrintScreen, so the png image maybe a bit incorrect. However the pdf is okay.